# Javascript Filter Row by element.data

Tags: javascript, jquery, filter

I am trying to filter my table by a certain column value when the button with the same value is clicked and i want to hide the other values that aren't selected. I am trying to pull the value of data-product. The filter does not seem to be working at all. Here is my code from my scripts file.

```
$('.filter-btns.top input').on('click', function () {
    $('.filter-btns.top input').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
});

$('.filter-button').on('click', function () {
    var button = $(this);
    var name = button.attr('name');
    var count = 0;


    $('#results-tbody tr').each(function () {
        var element = $(this);
        element.data('filters', element.data('filters').replace(/button/g, ''));
        switch (name) {
            case 'flexitouch':
                if (element.data('product') !== "flexitouch") {
                    element.data('filters', element.data('filters') + 'button');
                }
                break;
            case 'actitouch':
                if (element.data('product') !== "actitouch") {
                    element.data('filters', element.data('filters') + 'button');
                }
                break;
            case 'entre':
                if (element.data('product') !== "entre") {
                    element.data('filters', element.data('filters') + 'button');
                }
                break;
        }
        count = count + hideOrShow(element);

    });
    setResultsCount(count);
});
```

Here is the cshtml file that it is referencing

```
   <div class="filter-btns top">
        <h4 class="filter-heading">Quick Search By</h4>
        <input type="button" id="all" name="all" class="button1 filter-button active" value="All" />
        <input type="button" id="flexitouch" name="flexitouch" class="button1 filter-button" value="Flexitouch" />
        <input type="button" id="actitouch" name="actitouch" class="button1 filter-button" value="ACTitouch" />
        <input type="button" id="entre" name="entre" class="button1 filter-button" value="Entre" />
    </div>
  <table class="table results-table">
            <tr>
                <th><i id="count"> (@ViewBag.Count found) </i></th>
            </tr>
            <tbody id="reults-tbody">
                @foreach (var item in Model.SearchResults)
                {

                    <tr class="table__row-link" data-patientname"="@item.PatientLastName , @item.PatientLastName" 
                        data-product="@item.Product.Replace("+","")" data-referral="@item.d_Order_Date" data-oc="@item.d_Order_Complete_Date"
                        data-approved="@item.ApprovedDate" data-inactive="@item.d_Inactive_Date" data-training="@item.LastTrainedDate" data-links="@item.Links" data-filters="none">
                        <td>

                            <a href="@Url.Action("Details", "Patient", new { patientID = item.PT_RecID })">
                                <strong>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PatientLastName, item.PatientFirstName) (@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PT_RecID))</strong>
                                <br />
                                <strong>Product: </strong>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Product)
                                <br />
                                <strong>Referral: </strong>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.d_Order_Date)
                                <br />
                                <strong>OC: </strong> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.d_Order_Complete_Date)
                                <br />
                                <strong>Shipped: </strong> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.d_Ship_Date)
                                <br />
                                <strong>Approved: </strong> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ApprovedDate)
                                <br />
                                <strong>Inactive: </strong> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.d_Inactive_Date)
                                <br />
                                <strong>Training: </strong> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LastTrainedDate)
                                <br />
                                <strong>Links: </strong> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Links)
                                <br />
                            </a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                }
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using the build-in `.filter()` method.
When you have an array of users you can use this method to create a new filtered array.

Example of use:

html

```
<button class="agetrigger" data-age="25">25</button>
<button class="agetrigger" data-age="22">22</button>
<button class="agetrigger" data-age="28">28</button>
```

js

```
 const students = [
  {
    "index": 0,
    "isActive": false,
    "age": 25,
    "eyeColor": "blue",
    "name": "Roach Hunter",
    "gender": "male"
  },
  {
    "index": 1,
    "isActive": true,
    "age": 22,
    "eyeColor": "brown",
    "name": "Dena Terrell",
    "gender": "female"
  },
  {
    "index": 2,
    "isActive": true,
    "age": 28,
    "eyeColor": "blue",
    "name": "Vanessa Guthrie",
    "gender": "female"
  }
];

var filterAge = null;
$('.agetrigger').on('click', function() {

  filterAge = $(this).data('age');    
  const getAgeStudent = students.filter(student => student.age >= filterAge);

  console.log(getAgeStudent);
});
```

As an result I have a new array with the filtered student.
In your case you should store the condition of what should be returned in a variable an pass that to the method.

---

Update:
I have used jQuery to update the solution.
[JSFiddle exmaple](https://jsfiddle.net/453ro43b/1/)

Comment: what does that look like?

Comment: That didn't seem to work. The page is still not filtering.